# Refer to constant or package level variable instead of function level variable

Tags: go, scope, reference, identifier

```
package main

import "fmt"

const name = "Yosua"
// or var name string = "James"

func main() {
    name := "Jobs"
    fmt.Println(name)
}
```

How to refer to the constant and not the the function level variable?

Comment: This will not compile. I have to ask, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Ah sorry i forgot to delete the package level variable, so it can't compile. I just want to make sure that Golang can do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. While the local variable `name` is in scope, the name `name` denotes the local variable. And there is no "qualifier" to refer to top-level identifiers.

[Spec: Declarations and scope:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope)

> An identifier declared in a block may be redeclared in an inner block. While the identifier of the inner declaration is in scope, it denotes the entity declared by the inner declaration.

If you need to access both the top-level constant/variable and the local variable at the same time, use different names.

If for some reason you can't or don't want to, you may save the value of the top-level constant or variable first:

```
cname := name
name := "Jobs"
fmt.Println(name)
fmt.Println(cname)
```

Or you may provide other means to access it, e.g. a function:

```
func getName() string {
    return name
}

name := "Jobs"
fmt.Println(name)
fmt.Println(getName())
```

Output in both cases (try them on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/h5zkXh8m6X)):

```
Jobs
Yosua
```