# Cannot access global variable inside function

Tags: variables, go, struct

I have the following code:

```
package main

import (
  "net/http"
  "log"
  "net"
  "fmt"
  "os"
  "encoding/json"
)

const configName string = "config.json"

type Config struct {
 UDPServerAddress string
 HTTPServerAddress string 
}

var config Config

func UDProutine (query string, ch chan<- string) {
  log.Fatal(config.UDPServerAddress)
}

func main () {
  file,_ := os.Open(configName)
  defer file.Close()
  decoder := json.NewDecoder(file)
  config := Config{}
  err := decoder.Decode(&config)
  if err != nil {
     fmt.Println("error",err)
  }
  log.Fatal(config.UDPServerAddress)
}
```

And in my `config.json`

```
{
  "UDPServerAddress":"127.0.0.1:54",
  "HTTPServerAddress":"127.0.0.1:8082"
}
```

My question is, why does it log the config data correctly inside `main` but its empty value when logged inside `UDPRoutine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `main()` you used the same name: `config` for a local variable. This will shadow the global variable. After this point, you can't refer to the global variable (for details, see [Refer to constant or package level variable instead of function level variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496954/refer-to-constant-or-package-level-variable-instead-of-function-level-variable/38497376#38497376)). You load the config into this local variable, but the global `config` will remain unchanged (zero), and the `UDProutine()` function will read / print this global variable.

If you want to load the config to the global variable, don't create a local `config` variable. Just delete this line:

```
config := Config{}
```

**Note:**

The above line is a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) which creates a new variable.

You most likely just wanted to assign an empty `Config{}` struct value to `config`, but for that you have to use an [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments):

```
config = Config{}
```

But this is not needed in this case, as the global variable declaration:

```
var config Config
```

will initialize the `config` global variable to its [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value), which in case of structs is a struct value where all its fields are also initialized to the zero values of their types.

Comment: ok how do i fix that?

Comment: My only question is it was never instantiated then?

Comment: @jkushner Declaring a variable will initialize it to its zero value. Since your `Config` type is a struct, its zero value is a struct with all its fields being the zero values of their types. And since it has fields of `string` type, their values will be the empty string.

Comment: i see. thanks for the help